# Uma query MySQL, com `crases` vs sem

Tags: mysql, sql, segurança

Com crases a `query` é mais segura ou menos?

```
$Query = "Select * from `tabela` WHERE `id` = `1`";


vs

$Query = "Select * from tabela WHERE id = 1";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depende. Se você souber o que está fazendo, qualquer uma. Se não souber, é melhor a primeira, assim você evita conflitos que possam surgir e não sabe como resolver. Alguns programadores adotam esta forma por padrão, outros adotam a segunda forma e só quando precisa se utilizar do *backtick*, o nome correto disto, é que o usa.

Não dá mais segurança fazer isso, segurança vem de práticas corretas. Isso ajuda evitar certos tipos de conflitos ou inconsistências, como usar caracteres que podem confundir a sintaxe da *query*, o espaço por exemplo, ou palavras reservadas. Se você sabe e organiza bem os nomes das coisas, ele não ajuda muito.

Em alguns casos pode ajudar na segurança e evitar [SQL injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101) mas não conte com isto para resolver este problema, esta medida pode ser contornada. O recurso não foi inventado para resolver problemas de segurança.

É bom saber que esta forma não está disponível em todos os bancos de dados. Se precisar usar a *query* para outro, pode ter problemas. Mas se precisa deste recurso, provavelmente terá vários outros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que será que tem de errado na resposta? Ou será que foi voto negativo estratégico?

Comment: Foi mal, esqueci de dar o motivo. Não foi estratégico ahahah Foi porque na minha opnião realmente se trata de uma resposta errada, porque não *Depende* de nada, existe um motivo claro para uso dos `backticks` e também não é uma questão de *alguns programadores adotam esta forma por padrão*, novamente, existe um motivo claro para seu uso, não é questão de padrão e sim de necessidade. *Se não souber é melhor a primeira*, não faz o menor sentido. =)

Comment: Como você disse, esta é a sua opinião. Talvez você não saiba que muitos programadores usam sempre para evitar problemas. E eles fazem isto porque não sabe o que está fazendo. O fato de você não saber disto não torna a resposta errada. A sua está mais errada porque a pergunta fala em segurança e você não toca no assunto. Você pinçou um trecho do texto para tirar do contexto e parecer que tem erro. A única coisa que ficou estranha é que eu não terminei a frase. Adicionei o exemplo para ficar mais claro do que estou falando, mas falei do problema que você se refere.

Comment: Entendo seu ponto de vista mas ainda discordo :) Qual tipo de problemas um programador evitar usando `backticks` a não ser o único motivo pelo qual eles existem? Se o programador não sabe o que esta fazendo, ele não esta fazendo, esta copiando, o que em sí já é um grande erro, se não sabe, o programador deve ler e entender. Minha resposta não esta mais errada porque ela explica o **real** uso dos `backticks` que no caso, não tem nada a ver com segurança, por isso não toquei no assunto. Pela pergunta se entende que o usuário não sabe o uso do `backtick` daí a minha resposta, ao invés de...

Comment: continuar prologando o seu * E eles fazem isto porque não sabe o que está fazendo* , eu expliquei a ele o motivo de se usar ou não os `backticks`, somente por essa razão eu já considero minha resposta correta, porque ao invés de manter o usuário no *Depende* ou outras explicações superficiais, eu expliquei do que realmente se trata.

Comment: Não estou te criticando ou querendo te atacar ok? Não entenda errado, é uma questão de opinião :)

Comment: Mas é o que quase todo programador faz. É justamente o que estou dizendo. Mas você prefere entender o que quiser. Você quer ignorar isto, ignore. A pergunta é sobre segurança, não sobre o que é o *backtick*. Você resolveu por conta própria achar que ele não sabe o que é isto. Pode até dizer o que é, sem problemas. Eu também disse, corretamente, **nada errado**. Mas ele perguntou sobre segurança. Eu respondi dentro do contexto da pergunta, você deu uma resposta genérica sobre o recurso. Você só não gostou da minha resposta, o que não é motivo para negativo. Mas se é a sua opinião...

Comment: Sem entrar na discussão, mas creio que a resposta aborda todos os pontos e contrapontos do uso dos `backticks`. Negativação por conta da opinião acerca de *depender* ou não do uso, é um tanto *radical*.

Comment: Por que apenas o MySQL (até onde sei) faz uso deste recurso? Vejo muitos código que fazem uso, porém se eles não implicam em nada de segurança, apenas no uso eventual de uma palavra reservada, qual a verdadeira utilidade destes `backticks`?

Comment: @bruno101 não faço ideia

Comment: @Maniero, não sei se pode ser util a sua resposta, mas é exemplo prático de que o uso de backticks previne a injeção de SQL veja https://paiza.io/projects/gL1_oz-MXlPP5p-dW4hZkg?language=mysql

Comment: Fica como comentário mesmo, porque dá pra contornar isso.

Answer (score 13):

Em relação a segurança, não, `backticks` não tem envolvimento algum com segurança.

Os `backticks` são usados caso você utilize alguma [palavra reservada do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) ou quando tem espaço.

O primeiro exemplo do link já vai direto ao ponto:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE interval (begin INT, end INT);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax ...
near 'interval (begin INT, end INT)'

mysql> CREATE TABLE `interval` (begin INT, end INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Em casos de espaços não pode ser usado as aspas? Alias, até onde conheço, nunca vi uma coluna com espaço no nome.