# PHP Erro retornar função

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Tenho a seguinte classe com os metodos:

```
<?
class minhaClasse extends database {
public function funcao ($iduser) {
        $date = array($iduser, '1');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE 'iduser' = ? AND 'princ' = ? ";
        $result = parent::selectDB($sql, $date);
        if (count($result) == 0) {return 0;} else {
            foreach($result as $r) {
                $return =  $r->id;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

}
?>
```

no meu arquivo principal tenho a seguinte funcionalidade

```
<?
$minhaClasse = new minhaClasse;
$id = $minhaClasse->funcao($idUser); // *
if ($id == 0) {
echo "wem result";
} else {echo $id; }
?>
```

Bom porém sem nenhum echo nada tenho o seguinte retorno `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`
Mesmo tendo ou não tendo resultado no sql.
Fui analisando o código e vi que a linha que causa o problema é a *.
A classe datebase esta ok pois uso vários outras funções com ela...
Como poderia arrumar ?

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79846/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema para se a sintaxe, não se usa aspas simples(`'`) em nomes de colunas ou tabelas, para escapar nomes use backsticks `

```
WHERE 'iduser' = ? AND 'princ'
```

Trate o erro da consulta, verificando o retorno de `execute()`, isso facilita dectectar e resolver o problema com a consulta.

```
if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo amigo, obrigado

Comment: @AugustoFurlan, esqueci de falar, evite usar `<?`, prefira `<?php`

Comment: Sim, eu uso, mas como montei para passar pro forum acabei colocando por praticidade ...