# Qual a diferença entre aspa simples ' e aspa dupla " no SQL?

Tags: sql, característica-linguagem, sintaxe, estilo-de-codificação

#### Contexto

Quando faço um SQL e desejo por um alias especifico devo por entre aspas duplas `"`.

```
SELECT A.ds_nome_pessoa AS "Pessoa.nome" ...
```

Quando quero fazer um `where in` de um campo `varchar` os valores devem estar em aspa simples `'`.

```
WHERE A.ds_nome_pessoa IN (
    'Jose',
    'Maria',
    'Joao'
)
```

#### Pergunta

Qual a diferença entre aspa simples `'` e aspa dupla `"` no SQL?

#### Adendo

Se eu fizer um `SELECT` de `SELECT` - `SUBQUERY` - de campos que tem alias em `"`, o meu `SELECT` mais externo também deve ter `"`.

```
SELECT "Pessoa.nome" FROM
(
SELECT A.ds_nome_pessoa AS "Pessoa.nome" ...
)
```

Comment: Veja se pode te dá uma ajuda. Mais de qualquer forma grande pergunta.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql.

Comment: Pelo menos no postgres um nome de identificar com letras maiusculas precisa de aspas duplas ... :P nesse caso é só dar o alias em caixa baixa.

Comment: Falando do **PHP**, se usa aspas duplas quando no meio da expressão há uma variável, `$var`. Quando não tem usa aspas simples. Se você fizer: `$var = 5; echo '$var';`, não vai mostrar `5` e sim `$var`. Se fizer `echo "$var";` mostrará o valor da variável.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Em SQL padrão só apóstrofes (aspas simples) são reconhecidos como delimitador de literais *strings* ou algum outro tipo de dado (acredito que para outros tipos seja específico e não padrão). Fornecedores específicos admitem o uso das aspas duplas para a mesma função, mas isso pode variar, alguns exigem configuração. Exemplos que admitem o uso são MySQL, SQL Server e Oracle.

Alguns bancos de dados usam uma delas ou ambas para criar um alias de coluna, aí não precisa usar o `AS`. Mas é específico e não padrão. Melhor usar o padrão que é não ambíguo. O padrão determina que o alias seja com aspas duplas, ou sem elas. Todos os principais bancos aceitam o padrão, mesmo que precise configurar isso.

Todos os bancos SQL *mainstream* usam as aspas (duplas) para delimitar o nome de um identificador (nome de tabela, coluna, alias, etc.), alguns permitem configurar como vai usar. [Alguns usam o *backtick* (crase) para fazer isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79846/101). Outros usam os colchetes `[]` (SQL Server). O delimitador pode ser necessário quando há espaço no identificador ou usa uma palavra reservada. Pode variar de acordo com o fornecedor.

[Configuração do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html):

```
SET GLOBAL SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES
```

[Configuração do SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx):

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Other/QuoteConfig.sql).

Há casos, como o PostgreSQL, em que o uso das aspas duplas faz com que o nome do identificador considere a sensibilidade de caixa, o que não é normal do SQL. É bom ter certeza do que está fazendo e se é isso que deseja. O uso das aspas duplas são necessárias, junto com `&U` para escrever caracteres Unicode, mas é melhor evitar o seu uso.

Lembre-se que o uso de delimitadores quase nunca são necessários para identificadores. Se a pessoa quiser eles nunca são necessários. Pra mim os delimitadores só deveriam ser usados em literais. E se precisar usar no identificador mesmo, que seja uma exceção extrema.

Tem que consultar a documentação específica de cada fornecedor ou fazer perguntas específicas aqui.

Não encontrei nada em documentação que faça os elementos literais *string* do operador `IN` serem escritos de uma forma ou outra, eu conto com a documentação e ela diz que o ANSI deve usar aspas simples.

## Opção

Um outro motivo para usar aspas simples no SQL é que é normal a consulta ser montada dentro de outra linguagem por *strings* que provavelmente estará delimitada pelas duplas, então é melhor evitar confusão. Se a linguagem usada costuma delimitar *strings* com a simples, então é melhor usar a dupla no SQL.

Escolha uma forma de uso e fique com ela, não fique trocando sem motivos. Só o faça se tiver um bom motivo para fazer exceção. Faça se houver motivos que atrapalhem o SQL do fornecedor que estiver usando ou a linguagem hospedeira da montagem da consulta.

Note que o padrão do SQL são as aspas simples. E o padrão de todas as linguagens *mainstream* que eu conheço são as aspas duplas, ainda que possa, e alguns prefiram, usar as simples nessas linguagens. Eu particularmente adoto esse padrão porque ele funciona bem em mais de 99% dos casos. O padrão contrário funciona bem em bem menos casos, dependendo do banco de dados, algo até próximo de 99%, mas há casos que praticamente não funciona. Vai que um dia precise adaptar o código para outro banco...

A conclusão é que é melhor só usar aspas duplas onde realmente é absolutamente obrigado. Se eu encontrasse alguma situação onde fosse obrigado - acho que nunca encontrei - eu tentaria achar uma solução diferente. Não sei se todos concordam.