# Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu usava o MySQL e PHP no wampserver, agora coma última versão ele usa o MySQLi estou tendo problemas com o seguinte comando:

```
// Executa uma consulta que pega cinco notícias
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'usuarios'";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo 'ID: ' . $dados['id'] . '';
    echo 'Título: ' . $dados['nome'] . '';
}
echo 'Registros encontrados: ' . $query->num_rows;
?>
```

Está dando erro:

> Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\consulta.php on line 17

Comment: Sua consulta tem um erro, não vai aspa simples no nome da tabela.

Comment: A pergunta foi editada e aprovada mas a formatação não foi aplicada. Galera ta aprovando no automático, sem conferir se a edição de fato melhora a leitura da pergunta.

Comment: Funcionou muito Obrigado, estou apanhando um pouco com o mysqli, até agora não consegui fazer um sistema de login com sessão com ele. Mais estou procurando, VLW

Comment: Poderia marcar a resposta que resolveu o problema como aceita? fica um sinal verde. Veja [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 3):

> Call to a member function fetch_assoc()

Ao se deparar com o erro acima, significa que sua consulta falhou, para saber a origem do erro verifique a linha anterior a chamada `fetch_assoc()` que é `$mysqli->query($sql);`.

para conseguir alguma dica de qual foi o real problema veja qual é o retorno de `mysqli->error`.

No seu caso, tem aspas simples no nome da tabela, o que causa um erro de sintaxe, aspas simples são apenas para valores e não para escapar nomes de identificadores.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'usuarios'";
```

A mensagem de erro retornada é:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tabela'' at line

Aquele código 1064 chama-se SQL State ele identifica qual é a categoria do erro e fornece uma valiosa dica de como resolver o problema. 1064 significa erro de sintaxe.

Código com  verificação de erro:

```
$query = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->errno .' - '. $mysqli->error);
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Ou ainda

```
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
if(!query){
    echo 'erro: SQLState: '.  $mysqli->errno .' - '. $mysqli->error;
    exit;
}
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Documentação - MySQLi->error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

[Uma query MySQL, com crases vs sem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79846/91)

[Lista de SQL State MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use o comando fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)

```
require_once("conexao.php");        // Neste arquivo você cria a classe de conexão com o banco
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";

$con = Conexao::getInstanciar();    // Faz a conexao com o banco atraves de uma classe de conexao
$query = $con->executar($sql);

    while ($dados = $query ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo 'ID: ' . $dados['id'] . '<br>';
        echo 'Título: ' . $dados['nome'] . '';
    }
    echo '<p>Registros encontrados: ' . $query ->num_rows . '</p>';
```

Se precisar, esta é a classe de conexão com o banco MySQL `conexao.php`

```
class Conexao extends MySQLi {

    private static $host = 'localhost';
    private static $user = 'root';
    private static $pass = '*****';
    private static $base = 'seuBanco';

    private static $conectado = false;
    private static $instaciado = NULL;

    public function __destruct(){
        $this->close(); 
    }

    public static function getInstanciar() {
        if (NULL == self::$instaciado){
            self::$instaciado = new self(); 
        }
        return self::$instaciado;
    }

    public function conectar(){
        if (!self::$conectado) {
            parent::__construct(self::$host, self::$user, self::$pass, self::$base);
        parent::set_charset('utf8');

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                throw new Exception('A conexao falho: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
            }
            self::$conectado = true;
        }
    }

    public function fechar(){
        if (self::$conectado) {
            parent::close();
            self::$conectado = false;   
        }
    }

    public function executar($pSQL) {
        $this->conectar();
        $resultado = parent::query($pSQL);

        if ($resultado) {
            return $resultado;  
        } else {
            echo '<b>Erro na Query:</b><br>' . $pSQL;   
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo '<b>Erro:</b><br>' . mysqli_error($this);  
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo '<b>Número:</b>' . mysqli_errno($this) . '<br><br>';   
        }
    }

    public function estado(){
        if (@mysqli_ping($this)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eduardo, removi o markdown de tag que você inseriu no nome de arquivo ficticio do php, pois não era relevante pra este uso. o markdown de tag é pra quando você quer referenciar uma tag existente no site, assim, quando se clicar nela, o usuario será levado a uma pesquisa com o conteudo do site referente aquela tag.

Comment: Sem problemas. Ainda estou me acostumando com os recursos do stackoverflow. Ficou perfeito e obrigado pela dica. : )

Comment: A resposta ainda tem o mesmo problema da pergunta, erro sintaxe :P remove aquelas aspas simples de usuario no select.

Comment: Bem observado @rray. Removido e obrigado.