# Por que aliases com espaços funcionam apenas com backticks?

Tags: sql, sintaxe, mysql

Tenho uma *view* onde todas as suas colunas foram apelidadas para assim ficar mais legível:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CNPJ           | char(14)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DATA CADASTRO  | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| RAZÃO SOCIAL   | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| OPERADORA      | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LINHAS         | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CLASSIFICAÇÃO  | varchar(2)    | NO   |     |         |       |
| VIGENCIA       | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MESES CONTRATO | int(21)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| FIDELIDADE     | varchar(16)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| VALOR GASTO    | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| FIXO EMPRESA   | varchar(17)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| GESTOR         | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Note que há alguns campos onde existem espaço entre uma palavra e outra como por exemplo `RAZÃO SOCIAL` e se eu tentar executar uma consulta desse tipo:

```
SELECT * FROM listarclientes WHERE "RAZÃO SOCIAL" like "EMPRESA FICTICIA LTDA ME";
```

Ele não me resulta nada sendo que essa empresa existe no meu banco de dados. Agora se eu tentar fazer o mesmo porém com o uso dos *backticks*:

```
SELECT * FROM listarclientes WHERE `RAZÃO SOCIAL` like "EMPRESA FICTICIA LTDA ME";
```

Agora sim ele me traz o resultado desejado. **Por que consultas com  *aliases* que contém espaço no MySQL necessitam do uso de *backticks*?**

---

**NOTA:** nas consultas testei tanto com aspas simples `'` como com aspas duplas `"` e ambas resultam em branco.

**NOTA²:** a declaração dos *aliases* na `view` nesse exemplo foram feitas com aspas duplas `"` mas testei também com aspas simples `'`, e no caso sem nenhum tipo de aspas(como é o mais comum) não seria possível nesse caso pois ele é composta por duas palavras com espaço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque espaço encerra o nome do identificador. Não existem nomes com espaços. Identificadores são palavras, eles devem ter só nome, então vamos dizer que exista uma lei que exige que você só pode ter nome e sobrenome, mais nada, e você gosta do nome João Alberto, pra cumprir essa lei você precisa dar o nome do seu filho de JoãoALberto, assim fica uma coisa só. A maioria das linguagens tem essa lei porque ficar muito complicado para o compilador procurar resolver ambiguidades que pode gerar ter nomes separados.

Mas em modelos de banco de dados é comum as pessoas querem dar nomes esquisitos assim para fazer de conta que está descrevendo bem o problema como nome real da informação (isso nunca dá muito certo), então os *engines* de banco de dados costumam aceitar que você use esse nome com espaço, desde que crie uma forma de garantir que esse nome é uma coisa só, e essa forma é usar os *backticks*.

O use de aspas normais pode confundir com o literal de *string* e seria ambíguo também.

A solução simples é usar identificadores com nomes que um desenvolvedor entende, o usuário não tem acesso a isto, não é necessário essa bobagem.

Veja mais em [Uma query MySQL, com `crases` vs sem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79846/101).

Não vi alias algum na pergunta.

Comment: Todos os Fields da `view` são *aliases* do nome original da tabela. É uma bobagem mas com *backticks* funcionam, e acredito que serve apenas para o MySQL.

Comment: Isto não é alias. Não use nomes assim conforme eu falei e não terá essa dificuldade.

Comment: Ué se eu uso um `AS` para apelidar um campo ele se torna um alias, certo? Sim não utilizarei isso, com certeza é uma má prática só queria saber do funcionamento dos `bakcticks` nesse tipo de caso.

Comment: Isso é, o que você fez não é, você acabou de mostrar que são coisas distintas. O seu uso não é pra um tipo de caso, ele é ortogonal a todos os usos.

Comment: Sinto que estamos falando de coisas diferentes, estou falando na hora da criação da `view` que no caso não coloquei na pergunta, e lá eu apelidei todos os campos utilizando o `AS`, ficando assim a `view` como apresentado na pergunta. mas anyway isso não vai agregar em nada, o que eu perguntei você já conseguiu trazer a resposta.

Comment: Você não apelidou nada, você criou uma *view*, você está falando de algo que não existe. Se você usou *alias* no *view* e não colocou na pergunta eu não posso fazer nada, eu estou falando do que você colocou na pergunta, inclusive deveria ter colocado se é relevante para a pergunta, se não é nem deveria ter citado isso.